# regex /b word boundary to find word is not working

Tags: javascript, regex

How does `/b` work exactly? I need to find an exact match for a word in a sentence. I have the below regex and test:

```js
const values = 'sports is good'
const values2 = 'I\'m a sportsman' // shoud not match
const values3 = 'I\'ve done my bisports today' //shoud not match

function match(values) {
  return values.match(new RegExp('sports' + '\\b', 'i')) ? true : false
}

alert(match(values)) //true
alert(match(values2)) // false
alert(match(values3)) // I expect this to be false coz it isn't really an exact match
```

Why the 3rd alert is true? I expected that to be false because `bisports` isn't really `sports`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your regex, you have only included a word boundary at the end of the word.

Add one at the beginning as well to only match the exact word:

```
  return values.match(new RegExp('\\b' + 'sports' + '\\b', 'i')) ? true : false;
```

Here's a complete snippet:

```js
const values1 = 'sports is good';
const values2 = 'I\'m a sportsman';
const values3 = 'I\'ve done my bisports today';

function match(values) {
  return values.match(new RegExp('\\b' + 'sports' + '\\b', 'i')) ? true : false;
}

console.log(match(values1)); // true
console.log(match(values2)); // false
console.log(match(values3)); // false
```